# How can I make matplotlib plot rendering faster

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqt4

I want to work with a scatter plot within a `FigureCanvasQTAgg`. The scatter plot may have 50,000 or more data points. The user wants to draw a polygon in the plot to select the data points within the polygon. I've realized that by setting points via mouse clicks and connect them with lines using `Axis.plot()`. When the user has set all points the polygon is drawn. Each time I add a new point I call `FigureCanvasQTAgg.draw()` to render the current version of the plot. This is slow, because the scatter plot has so much data. 
Is there a way to make this faster?

Comment: You should decimate your data points before drawing them in the scatter plot. If decimation is not possible, then you should only show the region where the user wants to draw the polygon. This should speed up your rendering.

Comment: There are 409 questions for [matplotlib "slow"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatplotlib%5D+"slow") and 354 for [matplotlib "faster"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatplotlib%5D+"faster"). Does none of them help? In that case, be more specific and tell us what you have tried and why it didn't help.

Comment: why do you need that many data points?  what's the end goal of this code?

Comment: @MohammadAthar the goal is to cut out certain points and write the reminder to a file. This is done easiest by visual inspection.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I do think that my question is very clear and specific. Comments a la "google is you friend" are not helpful.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest To answer you question: I don't know what else to do than plot, render, plot, render, ... Since the data (the scatter plot) and the `Lines2D`/`Patch` are in the same canvas, changing the `Lines2D` will be slow

Comment: Not providing the necessary code and not narrowing down the scope of the question simply lowers the chances of getting a satisfying answer. At the end, it's your choice. Personnally, I find it very unsatifactory to write a complete minimal example and do the reseach myself, thereby spending more time than the questioner on the solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I do understand your point. But the problem does not lie in the code. To present a working minimal PyQt4 code that reads data from a file, with Signals and user interface doesn't shed any additional light on the problem. What I expected as an answer could have been something like this: "1. render the scatter plot, 2. store the rendered data in a matrix 3. use `Axis.imshow()` to plot the matrix and 4. work on `imshow` plot instead of the scatter plot". I would loose resolution, but rendering the `imshow` maybe is much faster than rendering the scatterplot.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

1. Don't show a scatter plot, but a hexbin plot instead.
2. Use blitting.

*(In case someone wonders about the quality of this answer; mind that the questioner specifially asked for this kind of structure in the comments below the question.)*

Comment: Interesting idea, but I do have more than one colour. How about that: (I put it inot a seperate answer)

Answer (score 0):

I can try to convert the scatter plot into an image using matplotlib to render it and display the image with imshow:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT4AGG')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Image # PIL
from io import BytesIO
from matplotlib import image

plt.scatter(xdata, ydata)
plt.axis('off')
plt.subplots_adjust(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
stream = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(stream, format='raw')
pilImage = Image.fromstring('RGBA',size=(640, 480), data = stream.getvalue())
plt.imshow(image.pil_to_array(pilImage))
```